# Indeterminate form $1^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I've retrieved a certain formula from old classroom notes which solves a limit dealing with an indeterminate form of type $1^\infty$:
\begin{align}
L=\lim f(x)^{g(x)}=\exp(\lim[g(x)(f(x)-1)]) \qquad \mbox(1)
\end{align}

For $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1-2/x)^{2x-1}$, for example, the formula works well and yields $e^{-4}$ as a result. Would it be possible to find a proof of (1)? The textbooks at my disposal do not give any.

I tried to use l'Hospital rule after applying the standard transformation $$\ln L = \lim \left(\frac{\ln f(x)}{1/g(x)}\right)$$and came to
$$\ln L = \lim \left( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\cdot \frac{[g(x)]^2}{g'(x)}\right) \qquad \mbox(2)$$

How could equations (1) and (2) be related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\ln L = \lim \big( g(x)\ln f(x) \big) = \lim \big( g(x)\ln\big(1+(f(x)-1)\big) \big). \tag{$*$}
$$
Using the known fact
$$
\lim_{t\to0} \frac{\ln(1+t)}t=1
$$
and the assumption that $\lim f(x)-1=0$, we obtain
$$
\lim \frac{\ln(1+(f(x)-1))}{f(x)-1}=1. \tag{$*$$*$}
$$
Dividing ($*$) by ($*$$*$) yields your expression (1).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a direct method that works on all such problems.

If:

$L$ is finite

As $d \to 0$:

Let $x = a+d$

$g(x) \in ω(1)$

$g(x)(f(x)-1) \in L + o(1)$

Then:

As $d \to 0$:

Let $x = a+d$

If $g(x) \in ω(1)$ and $g(x)(f(x)-1) \in L+o(1)$:

$f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{g(x)\ln\big(1+(f(x)-1)\big)}$

$ \in e^{g(x)\big((f(x)-1)+o(f(x)-1)\big)}$ because $f(x)-1 \in \frac{L+o(1)}{ω(1)} \subseteq o(1)$

$ ⊆ e^{g(x)(f(x)-1)+o(1)}$ because $g(x) o(f(x)-1) = o(g(x)(f(x)-1)) \in o(L+o(1)) ⊆ o(1)$

$ ⊆ e^{L+o(1)} = e^L (1+o(1)) = e^L + o(1)$