# Elementary example for the indeterminate form $1^\infty$

Tags: limits, examples-counterexamples, education, limits-without-lhopital

I am talking math with a bright middle schooler, who has not even seen logarithms in class yet. (We have successfully introduced logs as the inverse of exponentiation.) She is intrigued by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oc0M1o8tuPo&feature=youtu.be) and indeterminate forms. We have discussed how "$1^\infty$" is really the same as "$0/0$".

I would now like to discuss an example of "$1^\infty$". Unfortunately, every example I can come up with, and everything I find on the internet, uses [that $\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}\to 1$ as $t\to 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/813377/51074), which is either "[a well known fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/813393/51074)", or an application of L'Hospital's rule - both of which I find unsatisfactory.

Is there a non-trivial example for the "$1^\infty$" indeterminate form (so, not just $1^t$ for $t\to\infty$) that can be analyzed using only the definition of the logarithm as the inverse function to exponentiation, without calculus or facts I would need to pull out of a hat?

Comment: $(2^{1/x})^{x^2}$ as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: Ask her  what happens if we compute $$\left(\frac32\right)^2;\;\left(\frac43\right)^3;\;\left(\frac54\right)^4;\;\left(\frac65\right)^5;\;\ldots$$ then use the calculator to show what actually happens.

Comment: Would the downvoter please be so kind as to elaborate? I would like to know how my question "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", so I can ask better questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who can forget the classic example:

$\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n}$?

If we expand $(1+\dfrac{1}{n})^{n}$ with the Binomial Theorem and compare terms with corresponding powers of $1/n$ for different values of $n$, we find that this function increases as $n$ increases without bound, but the function is bounded by the convergent series

$1+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{1}{2!}+\dfrac{1}{3!}+...$

So the limit is guaranteed to exis and is thus definable as $e$, from which the rule $[\ln(1+x)]/x\to1$ as $x\to 0$ follows.

Comment: I assume you mean $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ (not $\frac{1}{n}$ in the exponent). Yes, that one came to mind, it's just that the concept of "this sequence converges to *something*, so we will just call whatever it converges to $e$" may be a little hard for a middle schooler to grasp. I may just throw all these excellent suggestions at her and see which one sticks.

Comment: Crummy awakeninhlg for je. Care to explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just fix $k>0$ (e.g. $k=2$) and look at $(k^{1/n})^n$?

It is pretty clear intuitively that $k^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]{k}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$; on the other hand, clearly $n\to\infty$ when $n\to\infty$. Thus, you have the case $1^\infty$ which actually converges to $k$ (and not just converges to $k$ but is *constant*), which you chose arbitrarily to start with.

Now this is easy to expand with $(k^{1/n})^{n^2}=k^n$ or $(k^{1/{n^2}})^n=k^{1/n}$, which converge to $0$ and $\infty$ (in some order, as long as $k\ne 1$).

Answer (score 2):

We seek $f,\,g$ with $f\to1,\,g\to\infty$, say as $x\to0$, so that $f^g$ can have just any limit $L\in[0,\,\infty]$ or none. Examples:

- $f=e^{x^2},\,g=x^{-2}\ln L$ for $L>1$
- $f=e^{-x^2},\,g=-x^{-2}\ln L$ for $L\in(0,\,1)$
- $f=e^{x^4},\,g=x^{-2}$ for $L=1$
- $f=e^{-x^2},\,g=x^{-4}$ for $L=0$
- $f=e^{-x^4},\,g=x^{-2}$ for $L=\infty$
- $f=e^{x^2\sin(1/x)},\,g=x^{-2}$ for $\lim_{x\to0}f^g$ to be undefined.

The replacement $(f,\,g)\mapsto(1/f,\,-g)$ shows $1^{-\infty}$ works the same way, but nobody every lists that separately.